# Getting Started with iOS Newsstand App Automation

Tags: ios, mobile, automation, ios-ui-automation

I am currently testing few features of a newsstand app manually. The kind of testing I do is pretty basic. To list a few:

1. Launch and exit the App
2. Launch, Navigate to menus and Login, Logout
3. Launch, take screenshot of splash screen
4. Launch, test the color of some text.

and so on. As there are 100s of tests like this, I want to automate these.

I do not have a Mac. Are there any tools (open source preferably) for achieving this?

Please note that I am kind of learning this myself and my company would not provide the cost required at this time. Its more of a PoC. So, when I have something concrete they will support eventually.

Please advice what tool I can use to achieve this (I hear a lot of things about Cucumber but I dont know Ruby. I am willing to learn, if that is the only best tool available).

Also, a sample code snippet on how to launch a newsstand app on the real device through an automated way would be cool.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides a [Automation f/w](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20-SW1) as part of [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20-SW1).

There are various tutorials/getting started guides available. Try searching "UIAutomation getting started" in google.

Some other third-party options for iOS application test automation:

- [Monkey Talk](https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk)
- [Calaba](http://calaba.sh/)
- [Telerik Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/)
- [UI Spec](https://code.google.com/p/uispec/)

I had evaluated these tools some time back and decided to use Apple's UIAutomation f/w. It has many flaws but we have been able to use it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You will need OSX and XCode for automation.  All UIAutomation frameworks are based around the `instruments` executable provided by Xcode.

I can also recommend [the Illuminator framework](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator) which I wrote to overcome a lot of the bugs and shortcomings in Apple's UIAutomation.